# Bash script to clear history, question on better solution

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I'm trying to write a function for a shell to delete history files in a directory and delete ones that are not a current running process.  I'm running into a problem with the use case that no files exist and `xargs rm` is called with an empty argument.

Does anyone have suggestions on handling this empty case without using temporary files?

Thanks

```
function purge_hist {
    for i in $(comm -23 <(sort -n <(ls $HOME/.hist/history.* | \
             sed "s#$HOME/.hist/history.##"))  < \
             (sort <(for i in $(ps -ex -o pid | sed 1d); 
                do 
                   echo $i ; 
                done)));
                do 
                   echo "$HOME/.hist/history.$i";
                done | xargs rm -f
}
```

UPDATED SOLUTION works

Comment: By accepting the answr of @rici other people know your question is answered. Now you edited the question (I think you added `-f`), and the question is more unclear for others. Next time consider writing your problem as `function_that_generates_filelist | xargs rm` or `filelist=""; cat filelist | xargs rm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs rm -f` would be the simplest solution.

Comment: long day of coding

Answer (score 1):

@rici 's solution will be fine in the particular case of `rm`, but if you really don't want to run `your_command` (which can just as well be `rm -f`) when `xargs` doesn't get any input, you should rather use in this case:

```
xargs --no-run-if-empty your_command
```

Comment: But only if you have Gnu xargs.